# DLLs to include in mkboundle to create an standalone exe for debian:wheezy

Tags: docker, mono, debian

I used mkboundle to create an exe for a mono Project. I run mkboundle with the --deps and --static parameters on a container based on mono:3.10.

```
mkbundle --deps --static ./Gestion.Industry.NancyHost.exe <other dlls>... -o pp2
```

Then I can use the standalone exe on containers based on mono:3.10 (or seif/mono, based on debían:wheezy) but not on a container based on debian:wheezy without mono. It seems there are still dependencies on mono.
This is the error I receive:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error Initializing the configuration system. ---> 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section <startup>(/usr/src/app/Gestion.Industry.NancyHost.exe.config line 30)
at System.Configuration.ConfigInfo.ThrowException (System.String text, System.
Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Configuration.SectionGroupInfo.ReadContent (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.Configuration.Configuration config, Boolean overrideAllowed, Boolean root) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Configuration.SectionGroupInfo.ReadRootData (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.Configuration.Configuration config, Boolean overrideAllowed) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Configuration.Configuration.ReadConfigFile (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Configuration.Configuration.Load () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't a dll dependency but the mono dependency on machine.config. I added the --machine-config parameter in the mkbundle command and now it works.

> --machine-config FILE Uses the given FILE as the machine.config file for the generated application.